# stop auto scrolling when clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple HTML Code in combination with css and JavaScript.
When you are clicking on a link, your URL will be updated like `"#link1"`. Then the visibility of an overlay turn on visible, which is only shown at `"#link1"`

Now the problem:
When I click on the link my screen automatically scrolls to this overlay, but I didn't want that. 
I tried `"return false"` or `"event.preventDefault()"`. This works, but my URL didn't get updated, so my overlay will not appear.

Dose anyone has an idea how I can do this?

Also tried:

```
return null

event.preventDefault()

onClick

----html----
<!--The Link-->
<area href="#link1" shape="rect" coords="0,0,100,100" />

<!--The Overlay-->
<div id="link1" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        ...some text...
    </div>
</div>

----css----
.overlay {
    visibility: hidden;
    ... some other stuff ...
}
.overlay:target {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Hello, could you provide de full code in order for someone to help you? Regards.

Comment: If that works then you can update the URL by using `window.history.pushState('', '', '#link1');`

Answer (score 0):

Can you do it this way instead of using href="#link1", do href="javascript:void(0)", and make overlay property appear using jquery property link

```
      $('body').on('click','a', function(){
          //Something here
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by setting the `display` property of the `overlay` class to `none`
You need to create a function that will get triggered when the page is loaded or when a link that starts with `#` is clicked.
That function will get the hash of the url, get the corresponding element and set its `display` property to something other than `none`
This way the element won't be visible when the page loads or the hash is changed.

```js
if (document.readyState === "complate") onLoad();
else addEventListener("load", onLoad);

function onLoad() {
  var target = document.getElementById(new URL(document.URL).hash.substring(1));
  if (target && target.classList.contains("overlay")) {
    target.classList.add("active");
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll("[href^='#']").forEach(function(link) {
  link.addEventListener("click", function() {
    setTimeout(onLoad, 0);
  });
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  display: none;
}

.overlay.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#link1">Show overlay</a>

<!--The Overlay-->
<div id="link1" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    ...some text...
  </div>
</div>
```

The other simpler solution is to use `position: fixed` to make the elements position static and always have it on the view-port (elimination the need for scrolling).